# Method not allowed in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am getting an method not allowed error while submitting a select box.
I am sending file url and array from view. I printed these values from controller it works fine but when trying to insert into db I am getting an error MethodNotAllowedHttpException. The Routes are working fine if I use dd( $excelData) i am getting the data.

[image: Click here for error]

```
public function uploadExcelData(Request $request)
{
    $url   = request('link');
    $array = request('index');
     print_r($array);
     echo $url;

    $excelData    = (Excel::load($url))->get();

    if(!empty($excelData) && $excelData->count()){

        foreach ($excelData->toArray() as $key => $value) {

            if(!empty($value)){

                    $insert[] = ['JobTitle' => $value[$array[0]], 'Skills' => $value[$array[1]],
                                 'Package'=>$value[$array[2]],"Location"=>$value[$array[3]]];           
            }
        }

        if(!empty($insert)){
            Jobposting::insert($insert);
            return back();
        }else{
            echo "empty";

        }
    }
}
```

This is the blade file

```html
<?php
//print_r($excelHeaders);
 // print_r($dbHeaders); 
 // @dd($excelData);
 //echo $url; onsubmit="return insertOrder();"
 ?>
<form  action="{{ URL::to('uploadExcelFile') }}" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" onsubmit="return insertOrder();">
{{ csrf_field() }}
 <table>
@for ($i=1; $i < sizeof($dbHeaders); $i++) 
<tr>
  <td> <input type="text" name="" value="{{$dbHeaders[$i]}}" disabled="disabled" class="droptargetinputs inputfields">
 <!--  <input type="hidden" name="{{$dbHeaders[$i]}}" id="{{$dbHeaders[$i]}}" value=""> -->
  </td>
  <td>
   <select class="order">
   <option>Select</option>
    @for ($j=1; $j < sizeof($excelHeaders); $j++) 
      <option value="{{ $excelHeaders[$j]}}">{{ $excelHeaders[$j]}}</option>
    @endfor
   </select>
 <input type="hidden" name="link" value="{{$url}}">
  </td>
</tr>
@endfor
<tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="click"></td><td><!-- <input type="button" name="submit" 
onclick="insertOrder()" value="mapping"> --></tb></tr>
</table>
<div id="hidden"></div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function insertOrder(){
         var table  = document.getElementsByClassName("order");
         var array  = Array();
         for(i=0; i<table.length; i++){
           // array[i] = table[i].value;
           // alert(array);

            var hide   = document.createElement("INPUT");
      hide.type  ="hidden";
      hide.value = table[i].value; 
      hide.name  = "index[]"; 
      var attach = document.getElementById('hidden');
      attach.appendChild(hide);

         }


        }
</script>
</body>
```

My Routes:

Route::get('uploadHome','ExcelController@showUpload');

Route::POST('importExcelFile', 'ExcelController@importExcel');

/*Route::match(['get', 'post'],'uploadExcelFile', 'ExcelController@uploadExcelData');
*/

Route::POST('uploadExcelFile', 'ExcelController@uploadExcelData');

Comment: post the blade file

Comment: @Exprator I did can u check now

Comment: what is the method error? like 404 or 403??

Comment: @Exprator i added the image of my error can u check

Comment: the error is coming for the return back() in the controller, after posting you are trying to go back again, so change it to something like redirect back or redirect to some other route

Comment: @SandeepGarapati Did my answer solved your problem?

Comment: @Exprator thanks it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you double checked this:

> The Routes are working fine if i use dd( $excelData) i am getting the data.

I think the problem may be here:

```
return back();
```

I think there is a mess in your route verbs somewhere. So you could try to redirect like this:

```
return redirect('/my-route-that-works');
```

If this still does not work, you should post your routes file too because in this case, I think your routes are not "working fine".

Reading your comment and your update, it seems you wrote `Route::POST` in uppercase, that's not the right way. Try replacing:

```
Route::POST
```

By:

```
Route::post
```

Comment: i added my routes too can u check

Comment: OK! replace `Route::POST` by `Route::post`